# iOS NSNotification - how to safely ignore when coming out of suspended

Tags: iphone, ios, suspend, nsnotification

Sometimes, when the app I'm working on comes out of suspended mode, I need to make sure it does not respond to the notifications iOS has saved for it while the app was suspended.  Where's the right place to perform this cancellation where I can be sure my response code won't run?

I'm hoping that putting removeObserver is applicationWillEnterForeground would do the trick, but I couldn't find anything about this in the NSNotification doc.

Edit:
Let me add the details of the scenario:

The app I'm working on checks for changes to calendar events for the range of the next 7 days.  It refreshes it's data (requeries eventStore) at two times:
1.  When an NSNotification comes from the iPhone calendar about changes.
2.  The first time the app is able to on a new day, because the 7 day range has changed.

The design challenge I'm having is the case where both scenarios are true at the same time (the app returns from being suspended and it's a new day, and calendar events were modified while the app was suspended ).  I only want to requery the event store one time in that case.  My thought is to, in applicationWillEnterForeground, on the case that it's the first launch of the day, tell the app to ignore or drop any notifications.
I'm getting the impression my assumptions about how NSNotifications would work in this case might be off.   Any guidance would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Why not remove the observer from the notification centre in `-applicationDidEnterBackground:`?

Then you can start observing again in `-applicationWillEnterForeground:`.

Comment: Thanks fir the thought but the majority of the time,  the notifications that happened while the app was suspended are needed  But there are cases where it's not which are not evident until the app is becoming active again

Answer (score 0):

What NSNotifications come in while you’re suspended? Are you running a background task?

I can’t really think of a case where not responding to an NSNotification would be a good idea. They are effectively messages like any other, just with a different routing mechanism.

UILocalNotification would be a different issue.

Comment: David, I added the scenario I'm trying to address in the original comments.  I'm not running a background task but I do understand it that after an app comes out of being suspended, any notification that were sent (or were attempted to be sent) would then be acted on by (or resent to) the app

Comment: OK, I'm not familiar with EK, but it does talk about modification while your app is running. Which, if it's suspended, it's not. But I'll assume the documentation is misleading. On the other hand, is this something worth worrying about? Is querying for 7 days that expensive? If it really is, you could always set some "I need to be updated" state, then run a slightly deferred update (performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:) if that state is not already set.

Comment: performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: looks like the way to go for my case, as I'm also seeing that multiple EKEventChangeNotifications can gather as well (I thought the app would only receive one, max).  As for being an expensive operation if it ran twice, it's a good point that it probably isn't, but I store data from the EKevents in core data and updating that twice, and then having core data update the related FRC's which update the UI, doesn't sound good to me.